# MySQL - Query Returning Values Matching REGEX Patterns

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, iis

I have large tables of freely formatted text strings stored in MySQL database. Within each of those strings I have to find three substrings which are specifically formatted. This problem looks like an ideal fit for MySQL REGEXP pattern matching.

I know that MySQl REGEXP operator returns only True or False. Moreover, because I need to process large tables, I would need to achieve the goal within MySQL and not to involve PHP or any other server side language.

Example of source data:

```
FirstEntry_somestring_202320047A_210991957_700443250_Lieferadresse:_modified string c/o Logistics, some address and another text

SecondEntry_hereisanothertext_210991957_text_202320047A_and_700443250_another text which does not have any predefined structure

ThirdEntry_700443250_210991957_202320047A_Lieferadresse:_here some address, Logistics, and some another text with address.

FourthEntry some very long text before numbers__202320047A-700443250-210991957-Lieferadresse:, another text with address and company name. None of this text has predefined structure
```

The examples above have are four strings stored as TEXT datatypes within MySQL table. They do not have any specific structure. I know however, that somewhere in each records must be three numbers freely delimited and but they have specific format:

1. Regex Format: **'\d{3}(30|31|32)\d{4}[A-Z])'**
2. Regex Format:**'(\d{3}(99)\d{4})')**
3. Regex Format: **'((700)\d{6})'**

Could you please help me how can I get the substrings matching the Regex patterns in the text above?

The Server runs on:

- Windows OS
- IIS 7
- MySQL for Windows
- PHP
- ...

Thank you!

Comment: MySQL doesn't directly support this. You can use e.g. a package like [lib_mysqludf_preg](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg) that adds more regexp functionalities, or write a specialized function that walks through your string and extracts the 3 values. You should strongly consider to save your data directly in a normalized way when you insert/update your data (e.g. add the three values to seperate columns); you can use a regexp in your app (that adds the data) for this. Finding/using/checking data (e.g. the addresses) that is stored in one big text will keep giving you nightmares.

Comment: Hi Solarflare, thank you. Yes, plan is to pre-process the table, to extract the data I need and to save the three values into three separate columns. I have information about lib_mzsyludf_preq library. I can use it now, but not sure, if I can not use in in production environment. How would you design your function checking the string? Would you do substring index increments for specified substring length until your regexp returns true?

Comment: Some things are better done in application code.

Comment: @RickJames . . . Or using one of the several databases that support this functionality.  (Full regular expression support should really be in all databases.  Regular expressions have been around basically forever, are extremely useful, and compatible with relational models.)

Comment: hey guys, I would be happy to use another database system. If you were asked to develop a module for already running system, nobody wants to hear, that we have to switch the whole database software just because we need to solve one small task. It would be too expensive. Solving the regexp part with server-side programming language would be very slow. I think I have to focus on the capabilities of MySQL.

Comment: There must be a way to use MySQL Stored Procedures. Replacing the whole DB System would definitely bring more complications nobody wants to face.

Comment: I am working on a solution using stored procedures. Hopefully, it is doable

Comment: `\d` can be replaced by `[[:digit:]]` to _test_ the string.  (Granted, this does not solve the _extraction_ part.)

Comment: A Stored Proc _could_ be written to tediously extract every 9- or 10-character substring and test the substring against the regexp.  It would not be fast.

Comment: Exactly, I am using this approach. I will pre-process the table by extracting the values I need. After that, i will work with the tables as usual

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB 10.0.5 (from 2013) is virtually the same as MySQL, but it includes the full set of REGEXP.  Also it has `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.

See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pcre/

Comment: Hi Rick, as already mentioned. If you work in a corporate environment, you do not want to come with suggestion to replace their database system because you know no better solution. There are too many systems tweaked and depending on the existing MySQL. Nobody will take the risk, even if MariaDB would be 100% identical. Maybe for others? But for me this can not be a solution. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: I understand.  Maybe someone else will find this answer acceptable in their environment.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in this question, I have developed my own solution using MySQL Stored Procedures.

I think, this is the most valuable solution on this subject on StackOverflow, as it provides real solution. In contrast to others, there were only vague ideas offered:

```
-- Return REGEX Value
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS RETURNREGEX$$
CREATE PROCEDURE RETURNREGEX(IN strSentence VARCHAR(1024), IN regex_str VARCHAR(1024), IN length_str INT )
    BEGIN

        DECLARE index_str INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE match_str VARCHAR(1024) DEFAULT '';
        DECLARE result BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;

        REPEAT
            -- Get substring with predefined length
            SELECT SUBSTRING(strSentence, index_str, length_str) INTO match_str;

            -- compare this substring agains REGEX to see if we have match
            SELECT match_str REGEXP regex_str INTO result;

            SET index_str = index_str + 1;

        -- evaluate result (TRUE / FALSE)
        UNTIL result OR index_str > length(strSentence)
        END REPEAT;

        IF result = TRUE THEN SELECT match_str;
        ELSE SELECT NULL;
        END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```